# i have this error can anyone tell me the solution

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("loc-brightkite_totalCheckins.txt", usecols=["location_id", "user"], delim_whitespace=True, names=["user", "check_in_time", "latitude", "longitude", "location_id"])

# remove duplicates (regarding location and user)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["user", "location_id"])

#group by the locations, make each a series of users, count users
distinct_location_users = df.groupby('location_id')['user'].agg(lambda user_series: len(user_series))

# print top 10 locations
top_10 = distinct_location_users.order().tail(11)

print top_10

top_10.plot(kind="bar")
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5c9c8115e794> in <module>()
      6 
      7 # remove duplicates (regarding location and user)
----> 8 df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["user", "location_id"])
      9 
     10 #group by the locations, make each a series of users, count users

TypeError: drop_duplicates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subset'
```

Comment: Look at `drop_duplicates`'s documentation or source code, apparently subset is not a keyword argument for it.

Comment: From the error text itself, _"got an unexpected keyword argument"_, so `subset` is not a keyword argument for the `drop_duplicates` method.

Comment: Please do at least the minimal amount of research: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: Give the guy a break...

.13.1 uses cols=
.14.1 uses subset=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

"subset" is not an authorized keyword for "drop_duplicates" method.

I think you can use "cols" instead of "subset".

Comment: In new version of pandas the `subset` is present: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `drop_duplicates` function in the wrong way. Have a look at what arguments pandas's drop_duplicates accepts.

A short googling on Panda drop_duplicates yields the documentation for one of two `drop_duplicates` methods in Panda (the other being for the class Series).

`DataFrame.drop_duplicates(cols=None, take_last=False, inplace=False)`